# Repo adding local project

Tags: git, repo

I'm using the [Angstrom distribution](https://github.com/Angstrom-distribution/angstrom-manifest/tree/angstrom-v2015.12-yocto2.0) with [Android repo tool](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html). But I also would like add a Yocto layer located in the local directory. Does anyone have an example of the syntax for the `manifest.xml` file that would allow this operation?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look that the source copy could be done.
However, there is a [document](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt) describing the XML fields in great details.